# Difference between copy_backward and reverse_copy?

Tags: c++, stl, generic-programming, std

I am reading C++ primer and saw these two functions that seem to have the same functionality. Could anyone help and tell me what is the difference between the two? Thanks.

Comment: You should bookmark this site: http://en.cppreference.com/w/ for future use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`reverse_copy` actually puts the elements in reverse order.

```
1 2 3 4 5 - > 5 4 3 2 1
```

`copy_backward` simply copies the elements backwards, but preserves their relative order.

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

5 is copied first, but put in the last spot. So your output is still:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward

> Copies the elements from the range, defined by [first, last), to another range ending at d_last. The elements are copied in reverse order (the last element is copied first), **but their relative order is preserved**.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy

> Copies the elements from the range [first, last) to another range beginning at d_first in such a way that the elements in the new range **are in reverse order.**

Comment: but whats the point of `std::copy_backward` if we can just `std::copy` ?

Comment: @0xB00B copy and copy_backwards handle overlapping ranges differently

Answer (score 2):

[`std::copy_backwards`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_backward) does:

> Copies the elements from the range, defined by [first, last), to another range ending at d_last. The elements are copied in reverse order (the last element is copied first), but their relative order is preserved.

[`std::reverse_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse_copy)

> Copies the elements from the range [first, last) to another range beginning at d_first in such a way that the elements in the new range are in reverse order.

So the difference is that `std::copy_backwards` start copying at the end and works backwards, keeping original positioning, whereas `std::reverse_copy` starts copying at the beginning going forward, but puts them in the reverse order.